# Node ExpressJS Post Request In Frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Nodejs and expressjs.
I'm trying to make a form submit to an express js backend. Here is the sample code.

```
var author = 'JAck';
var post = 'Hello World';

var body = JSON.stringify({
  'author' : author,
  'post' : post,
});

var request = new Request('http://localhost:3000/api/post',{
    body : 'body=' + body,
    method: 'post',
    mode: 'cors'
 });

 fetch(request).then(function(data){
     return data;
 });
```

And I have expressjs and body parser installed in the back end. And this is how my backend code looks like.

```
app.post('/api/post', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

However the console.log response is {} (blank). What am I doing wrong to not receive the data to the backend?

Please explain. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you're setting the content type to JSON

Comment: Express has explicit middleware for these kinds of things, [check out some examples](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters)

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question I am using expressJS and the middleware body-parser. So there is nothing wrong with the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are doing the request. You have tu use **form** instead of **body**

```
var request = new Request('http://localhost:3000/api/post',{
    form : 'body=' + body,
    method: 'post',
    mode: 'cors'
 });
```